# SQL Server pivot query without aggregate function

Tags: sql, pivot

I have one table Products, which stores master product info. The columns in this table are:

```
Products
========
ProductNo   Color   Size    Brand   Price
A            BLK     S        MS    12
B            BLU     S        SMS   13
C            RED     S        MS    14
```

I have another table OProducts. The columns in this table are:

```
OProducts
==========
ProductNo       Color   Size    Warehouse   IsActive    Price   Inventory
A                BLK    S         WP             Y       12        4
B                BLU    S         NWP            Y       13        5
C                RED    S         MS             Y       14        6
A                BLK    S         NWP            Y       12        7
```

I wish to display the data in this way.

```
ProductNo   Clr SZ  WP-IsAct    WP-Inve NWP-IsAct   NWP-Inve    MS-IsAct    MS-Inve
A           BLK S     Y             4      Y           7          --          --
B           BLU S    --            --      Y           5          --          --
C           RED S    --            --      --         --          Y            6
```

I think, I cant use a Pivot as there is no aggregate function involved.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can use MAX

Answer (score 0):

This is something that can be achieved by using CASE statements. The following query is how you could do that;

```
SELECT 
    x.ProductNo, 
    MAX(x.Color), 
    MAX(x.Size), 
    MAX(CASE WHEN y.Warehouse='WP' THEN y.IsActive ELSE '--' END) "WP-IsActive", 
    CASE WHEN y.Warehouse='WP' THEN SUM(y.Inventory) ELSE '--' END "WP-Inventory", 
    MAX(CASE WHEN y.Warehouse='NWP' THEN y.IsActive ELSE '--' END) "NWP-IsActive", 
    CASE WHEN y.Warehouse='NWP' THEN SUM(y.Inventory) ELSE '--' END "NWP-Inventory", 
    MAX(CASE WHEN y.Warehouse='WP' THEN y.IsActive ELSE '--' END) "MS-IsActive", 
    CASE WHEN y.Warehouse='WP' THEN SUM(y.Inventory) ELSE '--' END "MS-Inventory"
FROM Products x
JOIN OProducts y ON x.ProductNo=y.ProductNo
GROUP BY x.ProductNo
```

This query probably needs minor tweaking because I cannot test it right now but this would be the main idea.

The use of MAX() is necessary for columns that aren't part of the GROUP BY statement.

I also wonder why you would duplicate Color and Size in both tables since this is for both tables the same value for a certain product.

Comment: Ok great, maybe post a comment with your final query so that others with your problem can see the solution.